# How to enable inline editing inside table columns without a separate form in Wappler?

Tags: mysql, datatable, inline-editing, lowcode

I'm working on a web application using Wappler, and I have a table that displays data fetched from a database. I want to enable inline editing directly inside the table columns, without the need for a separate form, where you can click on a cell, edit the content, and then save the changes without leaving the table.

Most examples I found use a separate form for editing, which is not the user experience I'm aiming for.
Can someone guide me on how to achieve inline editing in Wappler without using a separate form? What are the steps and options available in Wappler to accomplish this? Any example code or tutorial would be highly appreciated.

I'm using Wappler version -v5.7.0
The table is populated with data from a database, and each row has a unique identifier (e.g., ID).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Check this https://github.com/sinhashubh/datatable-examples